# SQL query to change rows into columns based on the aggregation from rows

Tags: mysql, pivot, amazontimestream

I have a table, "MyTable" as below:

| tool | team | metric | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tool1 | team1 | 25 | 1/1/2023 |
| tool1 | team1 | 10 | 2/1/2022 |
| tool2 | team2 | 20 | 1/2/2022 |

I want to aggregate "metric" periodically by years (distinct years as columns) and have the sql query return something like this where value of 'year' column would be the sum of 'metric'

| tool | team | 2023 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tool1 | team1 | 25 | 10 |
| tool2 | team2 | 0 | 20 |

Can anyone help me such a query? For the cases, I need to first infer distinct years from the table, and then use that. And this list of distinct years needs to be from a time range. For this example, we could have time range denoted like this: `WHERE date between ago(600d) and now()`. That 600 value I will receive from the application, that's why the years are not fixed.

I have tried the to use 'pivot' but its not supported in the database engine I am using.

Comment: See the [pivot] tag.  Or [pivot-table] in stackoverflow.com .

Comment: Even though it is possible, I suggest you do this kind of operation in the application layer

Comment: This data is coming from aws timestream and pivot is not supported there. I can't do it in the application layer either because data is paginated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though it is possible, I suggest you do this kind of operation in the application layer. If you insist, you can use a conditional aggregate for each year:

```
SELECT tool, team
     , COUNT(CASE YEAR(date) WHEN 2023 THEN 1 END)
     , COUNT(CASE YEAR(date) WHEN 2022 THEN 1 END)
     , ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY tool, team
```

Also, avoid using reserved words as identifiers. Use identifiers that describes the attribute, your date column is probably a date of something in particular.

EDIT new requirements:

```
SELECT tool, team
     , COALESCE(SUM(CASE YEAR(dt) WHEN 2023 THEN metric END), 0) AS y2023
     , COALESCE(SUM(CASE YEAR(dt) WHEN 2022 THEN metric END), 0) AS y2022
FROM t
GROUP BY tool, team
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hkOowS5T)

Comment: Thanks! This helps. The one caveat that I have here with my case is that I can't type out the years (2023, 2022, etc) but want to infer it from my table; result of `select distinct(YEAR(time)) from ...`

Comment: Updated question to denote the conditionals

Comment: Not sure I understand. you can join with that, but then you will have to use the year as a dimension (to be able to know which year is which) and then you are almost back to where you started

Comment: @jenny edited answer and added fiddle

Comment: Yeah doing it on a query is nasty. Basically what I need to be able to do is:
```
COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(date) IN (select distinct(YEAR(date)) from MyTable WHERE date between ago(600d) and now()) then 1 end)
```

Comment: Have a look at my fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/hkOowS5T. I don't see a difference between adding constants like 600 vs 2022 to the query.

Comment: The difference is of passing the timerange days (600) as a parameter vs having to write multiple case statements for all possible years. That would introduce having dynamic columns based on the count of distinct years. But I think that's the answer you provided works best for me. Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: If you need to generate the columns dynamically from the data, you need dynamic SQL if there's no built-in pivot operation.

Comment: COALESCE/SUM/CASE could be simplified to SUM(IF(YEAR(dt)=2023,metric,0))